# Enabling Editing in Excel vb.net (no value given for one or more required parameters)

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I am trying to download a file from my server, save it, and then open it in a dataviewgrid.

When I download the excel file manually, i have to open it, "enable editing" then save it. If I do this, my code opens the excel file correctly into the datagridview.

If I try to download the file automatically with the code then open it, i get an error of: "No value given for one or more required paramaters". However, if I open that same file and enable editing then resave it, the same exact code works.

Here is my code:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/himapps/opalreports/myexcel.xls","H:\myexcel.xls") 'Download File/Save File

Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\myexcel.xls; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select HP_Assignment, OPAL_Status, Quote, Request_Name as 'Access For', Description from [Sheet1$] where HP_Assignment = '" & User1 & "' or OPAL_Assignment = '" & LastName & "'", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "OPAL")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an Excel object and opening it that way?